# AppEngine RemoteAPI SocketTimeoutException

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using RemoteAPI to fetch entities from GAE Datastore, 300 at a time.

I'm doing something along the lines of:

```
while(!(emails = getEmails()).isEmpty()) {

  Filter filter = new FilterPredicate("email", FilterOperator.IN, emails)
  Query query = new Query("MyEntity").setFilter(filter);
  QueryResultIterable<Entity> result = ds.prepare(query).asQueryResultIterable();

  for (Entity entity : result) {
    System.out.println(entity.getProperty("name"));
  }
}
```

I'm processing something like 50k emails. The first time I ran this code it got to maybe 3/4 of the way, then it threw the following exception. Now it throws it after a single loop iteration is run.

```
com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiException: remote API call: I/O error
at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteRpc.makeException(RemoteRpc.java:160)
at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteRpc.callImpl(RemoteRpc.java:104)
at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:50)
at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteDatastore.runQuery(RemoteDatastore.java:156)
at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteDatastore.handleRunQuery(RemoteDatastore.java:115)
at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteDatastore.handleDatastoreCall(RemoteDatastore.java:93)
at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiDelegate.makeDefaultSyncCall(RemoteApiDelegate.java:57)
at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.StandaloneRemoteApiDelegate.makeSyncCall(StandaloneRemoteApiDelegate.java:47)
at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.StandaloneRemoteApiDelegate$1.call(StandaloneRemoteApiDelegate.java:58)
at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.StandaloneRemoteApiDelegate$1.call(StandaloneRemoteApiDelegate.java:54)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:891)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:690)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1324)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:37)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:94)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:972)
at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.OAuthClient.post(OAuthClient.java:54)
at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteRpc.callImpl(RemoteRpc.java:102)
... 12 more
```

I can't figure out what the problem is, but the code seems to be evaluating the for() condition before throwing the exception.

Could this be a quota problem? The quota details screen doesn't show any problems and I can't find any relevant information in the documentation.

Comment: I've tried running the exact same code today and it simply worked. I've executed it multiple times (trying to figure out if it was a quota-related problem), but I was **unable** to reproduce the problem. I still do not know what the problem was.

Comment: I get these very infrequently, but they are troubling.  Did you ever get a resolution to this?  I'd prefer to catch these if possible and retry.

Comment: I changed nothing and the next day it simply worked. All quotas were way below the limit. No clue what it was. :(

Answer (score 0):

For future readers of this question, if you see occurrences of `RemoteApiException: remote API call: I/O error` which are happening consistently and not intermittently, this could be related to a disruption in network connectivity or possibly a remote issue on the App Engine side.

If the first possibility is ruled out, the best course of action is to report the issue on the [Google App Engine issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list).

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, first, check your Internet connection. Then **clean all artifacts and build them again** by (with IntelliJ):

1. Go to `Build` => `Build Artifacts...`
2. Focus on `All Artifacts` => `Clean`
3. Focus on `All Artifacts` => `Build`